# explicit wait in protractor is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gulp, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am using browser.wait to handle spinner on login page but it actually waiting for the whole time which i have passed as a third parameter.

It should move on to next test case when home page appears after 15min as i have provided the 20mins wait. could anyone please help here.

```
  it('test case', function () {
      loginPage.login(browser.params.Login.username, browser.params.Login.password);
      browser.wait(function() {
        loginPage.Spinner().then(function(presenceOfElement) {
            logger.info('App is waiting for spinner to complete'+ presenceOfElement);
            return !presenceOfElement
        }, 20*60*1000);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Assuming you are waiting for the spinner to disapper -- Have you tried with the invisibilityOf expected condition? http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.invisibilityOf.

Comment: Could you post your `Spinner()` function ? It appears that it's not resolving the Promise - i.e. I'm reading here http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait

Comment: @bob.mazzo here is my page object function.                                         this.Spinner = element(by.tagName('a'));
 
this.Spinner = function () {
    return browser.isElementPresent(this.Spinner);
  };

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I'm thrown off by the double reference to `this.Spinner`. Perhaps something like:  var elem = element(by.tagName('a')); 
this.Spinner = function () 
{ 
   return browser.isElementPresent(elem); 
};`

And also, how many `<a>` elements do you expect to be present ? Just one ?

Comment: @bob.mazzo Ohh sorry for typo mistake,                             this.loginSpinner = element(by.tagName('a'));                                                          this.Spinner = function () { return browser.isElementPresent(this.loginSpinner); }; & yes only one tag we have on login.

Comment: Well, if your `login()` function is non-Angular, then you'll need to use `ignoreSynchronization` (which you probably already know). other than that, perhaps you could hard-code a test inside `login()` to see if the `<a>` is indeed present once your login promise is resolved...maybe using a `browser.sleep()` for example.

Comment: @bob.mazzo - I put browser.sleep in login & still the same results.    this.login = function(username, password) {
    this.userInput.clear();
    this.passwordInput.clear();
    this.userInput.sendKeys(username);
    this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
    this.loginButton.click();
    browser.sleep(11000);
  };

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rewriting the page object and the test to make it more clear what is going on in the test. Try this:

```
// loginPage page object
this.getSpinner = function () {
    return element(by.tagName('a'));
};

// test
browser.wait(function () {
    return loginPage.getSpinner().isPresent().then(function (isSpinnerPresent) {
        return !isSpinnerPresent;
    )};
}, 20*60*1000);
```

Comment: same results with above solution as well. test case is waiting for the entire 20mins even login spinner goes within 5mins

Comment: Are you sure your spinner element is not just hidden but still present in the DOM after 5 mins? In that case you'd need to test for `isDisplayed()` instead of `isPresent()`.

Comment: No after login element is not hidden because i put logger & it returns false.                                                                                          
Logger results-
downloadtrue
[2017-01-25 09:58:29.883] [INFO] [default] - App is waiting for initial content                                                                                                     downloadfalse
[2017-01-25 09:59:06.659] [INFO] [default] - App is waiting for initial content

Comment: Have you tried with the rewritten example? If `isSpinnerPresent` returns false, then `return !isSpinnerPresent` must break out of the the loop which `browser.wait` runs. I noticed that in your original post you are passing the timeout value at the wrong place. You are passing it to the `then` method instead of `browser.wait`.

Comment: Yes I tried the rewritten example but the same results. It waits for the whole defined time.